# My JS is not working (chat application)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, node.js

so following some previous things I've asked I ran into a problem with my JS. I wanted it in a different file for my chat system using Node, Socket.IO and JS. I used to have the JS in the index file but I want it in its own file.

I know that you need to use `app.use(express.static('public));` which I have done. My CSS works in a separate file in the directory /css/styles.css (In the public folder) but my JS does not want to work in the public folder.

My code in index.html to import it `<script type="text/javascipt" src="/js/java.js"></script>`. I don't know if that's wrong, if so please correct me.

Any help as to why my JS is not working would be great. Thank you.

Ok so adding on more information, I'm not getting any errors client side or server side at all. This is my entire JS file for the chat system.

```
$('document').ready(function(){
var socket = io.connect();
var $messages = $('#messages');
var $m = $('#m');
var $submitForm = $('#submitForm');
var $userFormArea = $('#userFormArea');
var $userForm = $('#userForm');
var $username = $('#username');
var $errorText = $('#errorText');
var $messageFormArea = $('#messageFormArea');
$errorText.hide();
$messageFormArea.hide();
$submitForm.submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  socket.emit('chat message', $m.val());
  $m.val('');
  return false;
});
socket.on('sent message', function(data){
    $messages.append('<li><strong>'+data.user+'</strong>: '+data.msg+'</li>');
});

socket.on('bad message', function(data){
    $messages.append('<li><strong>'+data.user+'</strong>: Was trying to send invalid character!</li>');
});

$userForm.submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
if($username.val() === ''){
  $errorText.show();
} else if ($username.val() === '<'){
  $errorText.show();
} else if($username.val() === '>'){
  $errorText.show();
} else {
  $errorText.hide();
  socket.emit('new user', $username.val(), function(data){
    if(data){
      $userFormArea.hide();
      $messageFormArea.show();
    }
  });
}
$username.val('');
});
});
```

Baring in mind this used to be in the index.html. Any fixes/solutions would be great. Thanks!

Comment: idk if this is going to solve but your `app.use(express.static('public));` is missing a `'` after the word 'public'

Comment: What error(s) are you getting? If at all possible, you should post a minimal complete example so we can reproduce and more effectively debug.

Comment: You've also misspelled `text/javascript`.

Comment: Make sure that your js file is in the directory "public/js/".  Also, @duskwuff and Taylor Foster's suggestions might help.

Answer (score 0):

The JS file wasn't working because I misspelled javascript.